# How to create foreign key relation on unique non-clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, database

In an existing table `Table1`, I have a column `StockNumber` which is neither primary nor unique due to valid reasons, so I cannot update it. I do have `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED` index on this table with 3 columns: `StockNumber, Location, CreatedDateTime`.

I am creating a second table `Table2` where I also have `StockNumber` column which should be a foreign key to `StockNumber` in `Table1`. Now given `StockNumber` column constraint in `Table1`, I can't use that, so I tried with index, but I am getting this error:

> Foreign key 'FK_dbo_Table2_StockNumber' references invalid column 'AK_dbo_Table1_StockNumber_Location_CreatedDateTime' in referenced table 'Table1'.

Questions:

- What am I doing wrong here?
- Is my desired result achievable with existing `Table1` schema? If not, what are my options.

`Table1` schema (existing)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [Table1Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, -- Primary key
    [Location] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [StockNumber] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TotalCost] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TotalCostSubmitted] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [EarliestPaymentDate] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [UpdatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo_Table1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Table1Id] ASC)
                    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                          ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [AK_dbo_Table1_StockNumber_Location_CreatedDateTime] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([StockNumber] ASC, [Location] ASC, [CreatedDateTime] ASC)
               WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                     ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

`Table2` schema (new table):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2]
(
    [Id] BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, -- Primary Key column
    [StockNumber] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [SupplierName] VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDateTime] DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] VARCHAR(225) NULL,
    [UpdatedDateTime] DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo_Table2] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                      ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- creating foreign key and getting error here.
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo_Table2_StockNumber] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([StockNumber]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Table1]([AK_dbo_Table1_StockNumber_Location_CreatedDateTime])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] 
    CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo_Table2_StockNumber]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [AK_dbo_Table2_StockNumber_CreatedDateTime] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([StockNumber] ASC, [CreatedDateTime] ASC)
               WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
                     ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Other approaches**

If I reference column(s) then,

```
-- creating foreign key and getting error here.
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo_Table2_StockNumber_CreatedDateTime] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([StockNumber], [CreatedDateTime]) 
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Table1]([StockNumber], [CreatedDateTime])
GO
```

I'm getting this error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.Table1' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_dbo_Table2_StockNumber_CreatedDateTime'.

Comment: You don't reference a constraint, you reference the column(s).

Comment: @ThomA I have updated my question with your suggestion but getting another error.

Comment: Your unique index isn't *just* on `StockNumber`, it's on `StockNumber`, `Location`, and `CreatedDateTime`. Your foreign has to be on all 3.

Comment: @ThomA that worked. So basically, I either have to update `Table1` index with `StockNumber` and `CreatedDateTime` if I just want 2 columns in `Table2` or add a third column `Location` in `Table2` to match the existing index. This is a good start. Let me see what I can do in `Table1`. Thank you.

Comment: The FK should have all three columns, not just `StockNumber`.